# From MatchCollection to Array or Pair of Values

Tags: regex, vba

Is there a way to put regex captures directly into an array without the intervening `MatchCollection`?

I want something like: `Set myArray = myRegEx.Execute(myString)(0).SubMatches`

Or at a minimum, if I knew the number of captures that I could "tie" the return values: `(myFirst, mySecond) = myRegEx.Execute(myString)(0).SubMatches`

I know that use of `SubMatches` is made up, I'm just trying to find a way to accomplish the circumvention of the intervening `MatchCollection`.

Comment: No. a `MatchCollection` object contains potentially multiple sub-objects (`Match` objects). If I'm understanding your request, you essentially want to translate those individual matches to an array (or 2d-array/collection with one of the match item's property values)? You can do this with a custom function, but you have to evaluate the `MatchCollection` and iterate it appropriately.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm new at VBA so I hope I'm actually saying what I mean. Say that I have this: `myRegEx.patern = "\s+([bBiI])\s+(\d+)"` When I `Execute` that like this: Set myMatches = myRegEx.Execute("some string with B 52")` `myMatches` only has 1 match. The `SubMatches` from that are what I'm actually interested in. But for some reason they're locked behind this wall of indexing into the `MatchCollection`.

Comment: Yeah I think your terminology is way off. For example you're talking about an array and you have a variable called `myArray` but you're using the `Set` keyword to assign it, and that requires an Object type, not an array.  Also, `Submatches` is very much a thing (you seem to know that, so I"m not sure why you indicated that it is "made up"...)

Comment: for `myArray` obviously naming doesn't really matter but in terms of making your code legible, it's good to use variable names taht are meaningful, i.e., don't call it an array if it's not an array, etc.

Comment: The real question is *why* you're trying to do this. Of course you can do `Set myArray = myRegEx.Execute(myString)(1).SubMatches` but that assumes that there is *always* at least one match, and doesn't offer you any insight about what to do if there are 2, 3 or 50 matches...

Comment: @DavidZemens Ugh... Thanks, yeah I know that `SubMatches` was a thing. I just didn't want to deal with indexing into them each time. I feel more comfortable working with arrays but perhaps that's a bad plan here?

Comment: You're **not** working with arrays, though, that's the rub :)  you're working with a `Match` or a `MatchCollection` or a `SubMatch`. Now if you need an *array of* these things (for example to pass to another client since only simple data types can be passed over COM) then that's another story. But if it's just a "comfort" issue, I'd encourage you to learn how to use the objects, rather than trying to always force things in to arrays.

Comment: @DavidZemens I am passing from an Outlook Macro to an Excel Macro. Is that COM? Again sorry for my ignorance. What I know how to pass is an array, hence my desire to get this into an array.

Comment: Nope let me give you some example chose when I get back to my desk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, maybe this will get you started.

From Outlook macro to Excel macro is not something I would do. Instead, I would recommend binding one application to the other and doing whatever you need to do with both object model references exposed to the VBProject.

But in any case you *can* do it the way you describe, and this should be an example.

This example assumes that Excel is already open, and further that the Workbook which contains the macro is also open in that instance of Excel.  In Excel I create a simple procedure which accepts a generic `Object` argument. I do this to avoid needing the explicit reference tot he Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library.

This way, you have a macro in Excel which accepts (requires, actually) an object variable. In this case it is going to be a `SubMatches` object.  (Make sure to change "Book9" to the name of your workbook, or modify as needed to allow user to select/open a workbook, etc.)

```
Sub excelmacro(SM As Object)

    MsgBox SM.Count & " submatches"

End Sub
```

Now, I have a very simple Outlook procedure to test this and verify it works. In this case there will be no submatches, so the Excel procedure above will display a messagebox `0 submatches`.

```
Sub test_to_Excel()
'### Requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.0 ###
Dim re As New RegExp
Dim mySubmatches As SubMatches
Dim xl As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim wb As Object 'Excel.Workbook

With re
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "asd"
    '## Now get a handle on the particular indexed match.submatches() 
    Set mySubmatches = .Execute("asdfkjasdfj; asdl asdfklwedrewn adg")(1).SubMatches
End With

'## Now we can send to Excel procedure:
'## Assumes Excel is already running and the file which contains the macro
'   is already open
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks("Book9")

'## This tells the Excel application to run a named procedure
'   and passes the variable argument(s) to that procedure
xl.Application.Run "excelmacro", mySubmatches

End Sub
```

Comment: One last question, was there any reason for the choice to use the currently open Excel Application over creating a new one?

Comment: No, it was just easier for me to create a simple example without having to deal with creating instance of Excel, opening a file (which would require that I had previously created & saved the file , etc.).  You should be able to do it either way :)